# EPIPE (Broken pipe) while uploading?

Tags: java, android, upload, httpurlconnection

i have a problem in my code but i don't know where is it the E log report

```
04-08 05:47:46.745: E/Upload Server(20080): Starting  : /storage/sdcard1/Music/Piano (my favourites)/11 Tchaikovsky - The Music Lovers.mp3
04-08 05:47:47.136: E/Upload Server(20080): Connection Error : sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

what is (EPIPE) ? , when i attempt to upload image its upload successfully but any other file E Cat report (Broken pipe) why !

this is my uploading code

```
   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


    String upLoadServerUri = "http://test.com/test.php";
    String fileName = this.file_path;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize =  1*1024*1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName);
    int sentBytes = 0;
    long fileSize = sourceFile.length();
    connection = null;


    try
    {


    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

    Log.e("Upload Server ", "Starting  : "+ fileName );

    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
    outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[]\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

       outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];



bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

   while (bytesRead > 0)
   {

   if(isCancelled()){

   break;
   }

   sentBytes += bytesRead;

   double percentDone = (sentBytes * 1.0) / fileSize * 100;
   publishProgress((int)percentDone);

   outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,     maxBufferSize);
   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,      bufferSize);
   }

   if(isCancelled()){

    fileInputStream.close();
   outputStream.flush();
   outputStream.close();
   Log.e("Upload Server ", "upload Canceled " );
   return "canceled";
   }

   outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
   outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
   int serverResponseCode       = connection.getResponseCode();
    fileInputStream.close();
   outputStream.flush();
   outputStream.close();

   if(serverResponseCode == 200)
   {
   Scanner s;
   s = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
   s.useDelimiter("\\Z");
   final String response = s.next();
   Log.e("Upload Server ", "Message : " + response);
   return response;
   }else
   {
   Log.e("Upload Server ", "Server Code Error : " + serverResponseCode );
   return "faild";
   }
   }  catch (final Exception e) {

   Log.e("Upload Server ", "Error : " +  e.getMessage() );
   }

   return "falid";
}
```

please note aim still newer in android apps :)
i googled my problem i couldn't found a solution please help !

Answer (score 8):

'Broken pipe' means you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

Probably you have exceeded an upload size limit.

You should also note that your use of `available()` is invalid. There is a specific warning in the Javadoc about *not* using it the way you are using it. You don't need it anyway:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

where `buffer` is any reasonable size, e.g. 8192 bytes.

Comment: when i removed the ( connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive") ) its worked but sometime Cat report connection Null !

Comment: HTTP keep-alive is the default actually. In any case it's hard to see why changing it should be expected to have any effect. I don't know what your last four words mean.

Comment: Yes it worked for some time but after that it stopped working.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Then you must have broken it. This code has been working for 17 years.

Comment: @JackKFouani 'Cat reported connection Null' cannot possibly be caused by this code. You got a prior error, possibly a connect exception.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem using `HttpURLConnection`. Just add:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close"); // disables Keep Alive
```

to your connection or disable it for all connections:

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

From the API about disconnect():

> Releases this connection so that its resources may be either reused or closed.
>   Unlike other Java implementations, this will not necessarily close socket connections that can be reused. You can disable all connection reuse by setting the http.keepAlive system property to false before issuing any HTTP requests.

So, Android will reuse the old socket connection. Disabling it with the code above you can fix it.